# .NET 4 SDK corrupted? with Silverlight 4 Tools install

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-2010

I installed [Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=9fa8afe9-cad6-4090-a7f6-7d9cdc560e2d) and now my C# projects that use some of the new .NET 4 classes like `System.Threading.Parallel` and `System.Numerics.BigInteger` don't appear to be present.

Have tried switching between selected frameworks in the project properties, and [downloading](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f5e8774-c8dc-4ff6-8285-03a4c387c0db&displaylang=en) and running repair on the .NET 4 SDK, but didn't resolve the issue.

Edit: Project act's like it's being compiled with .NET 3.5 SDK.

Comment: Why on earth would someone vote this to be moved to superuser.com??

Comment: Can you clear up something, the Parallel and BigInteger have gone missing or you projects have gone missing?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot apparently fixed the issue after the repair.